# Order the result by subject, ascending. Why putting subject after `ASC`?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

[SQL Basic Select Statement: Exercise-24 with Solution](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-exercise-24.php)

From the following table, write a SQL query to find the details of 1970 Nobel Prize winners. Order the result by subject, ascending except ‘Chemistry’ and ‘Economics’ which will come at the end of result set. Return year, subject, winner, country, and category.

[image]

Solution

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE year=1970 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner;
```

[SQL Basic Select Statement: Exercise-23 with Solution.](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-exercise-23.php)
In this solution, `year` is in front of `DESC`. I'm confused. Does the order of `ASC`,`DESC` and the column title matter? Like the one in exercise 24, both `subject` and `winner` are put after `ASC`. Are they both in ascending order?

Comment: The default sorting order is ascending.  So `ORDER BY subject, winner` means the same thing as `ORDER BY subject ASC, winner ASC`

Comment: Sorry, my question may not be so clear. I'm asking why `subject` is behind `ASC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL to order the result in ascending or descending, we have to put ASC or DESC keyword after the column name that we need to sort. For example, in Exercise 24 the ASC keyword is after the order by statement. This means the result is in ascending order according to your case.

In exercise 23 the DESC keyword is after the year. This means the result is ordered in descending order considering the year column.

So as a conclusion the keywords ASC and DESC are used after the field name that we want to arrange in order.

[Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) link for more details about orders by ASC and DESC.